# How can summarize all numbers in NSArray?

Tags: nsdate

I have NSArray with strings - 00:02:34, 02:05:17 so i need to calculate all strings in my array and get result: 2 hours:7 minutes and 51 seconds.

I tried this:

// Get strings from array for the first and separate for three objects by:

```
for (NSDictionary *dic in dicts) {
      NSString *string = dic[@"duration"]; (my type of string 00:00:00)
       NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        NSInteger minutes  = [components[1] integerValue];
        NSInteger seconds  = [components[2] integerValue];
        NSInteger hour     = [components[0] integerValue];
}
```

But how can i summ this date to get results? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could approach this.

Personally, I'd iterate through `dicts` and convert each `duration` string to *seconds* and keep count of the total seconds in an integer outside of the loop.

Then, you can easily convert the cumulative seconds total back into hours, minutes and seconds and compose a string from them, after the loop is complete:

```
int totalSeconds = 0;
for (NSDictionary * dic in dicts) {
    NSString *string = dic[@"duration"];
    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    totalSeconds += (int) [components[0] integerValue] * 60 * 60;
    totalSeconds += (int) [components[1] integerValue] * 60;
    totalSeconds += (int) [components[2] integerValue];
}

int hour = totalSeconds / 3600;
int mins = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
int secs = totalSeconds % 60;
NSString * totalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d", hour, mins, secs];
```

Note: you'll have to write a bit of code to compose the string and include zeros as appropriate, where any of the values are less than 10.